# Where is this difference between the solutions of DSolve and NDSolve coming from?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear, inverse

I am trying to solve this DE:

```
DSolve[{r'[t] == r[t]^2/3 (1 - r[t]), r[0] == 2}, r[t], 
  t] // Simplify
```

For which I get the solution

```
InverseFunction[Log[1 - #1] - Log[#1] + 1/#1 &][
 1/2 + I \[Pi] - t/3 - Log[2]]
```

After plotting the solution

```
Plot[InverseFunction[Log[1 - #1] - Log[#1] + 1/#1 &][
  1/2 + I \[Pi] - t/3 - Log[2]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

I get

[image]

However, the numerical solution using NDSolve results in:

[image]

How can I fix my DSolve result? I suspect the root finding process in the inverse function is a candidate? Because when I run

```
Table[{t, 
  InverseFunction[Log[1 - #1] - Log[#1] + 1/#1 &][
   1/2 + I \[Pi] - t/3 - Log[2]]}, {t, 0, 20, 0.5}]
```

some of the elements are not evaluated:

> {{0., InverseFunction[Log[1 - #1] - Log[#1] + 1/#1 &][-0.193147 + 
>       3.14159 I]}, {0.5,    InverseFunction[Log[1 - #1] - Log[#1] + 1/#1 &][-0.359814 + 
>       3.14159 I]},...

I am running MMA 10.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: Show more of your code, in particularly your first plot.  Does `PlotPoints -> 100` help?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question. I don't think it's the plotting part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, the numerical inversion of the DSolve solution,

```
s = DSolveValue[{r'[t] == r[t]^2/3 (1 - r[t]), r[0] == 2}, r[t], t] // Simplify
(* InverseFunction[Log[1 - #1] - Log[#1] + 1/#1 &][1/2 + I π - t/3 - Log[2]] *)
```

used to plot `r` as a function of `t` in the question is having difficulties.  An alternative approach is to plot `t` as a function of `r`.  First, extract the two arguments of the `InverseFunction`.

```
fun = Head[s][[1]][r]
(* 1/r + Log[1 - r] - Log[r] *)

arg = s[[1]]
(* 1/2 + I π - t/3 - Log[2] *)
```

equate the two, and solve for `t`.

```
a = (t /. Flatten@Solve[fun == arg, t]) // Expand
(* 3/2 + 3 I π - 3/r - 3 Log[2] - 3 Log[1 - r] + 3 Log[r] *)
```

Finally,

```
ParametricPlot[{a, r}, {r, 1, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, All}, AxesOrigin -> {0, .95}]
```

[image]

which reproduces the numerical solution in the question, as desired.

Comment: This is great,thanks! I don't know why someone down voted?

Comment: @MathX  Down-votes happen.  Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: Actually, your solution makes Inverse Function usage much easier, and I'll be using it for many other problems I am facing.

Answer (score 6):

It could also be view as a precision problem:

```
Plot[
 InverseFunction[Log[1 - #1] - Log[#1] + 1/#1 &][1/2 + I π - t/3 - Log[2]],
 {t, 0, 20},
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, WorkingPrecision -> 50, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course `InverseFunction` is much slower than @bbgodfrey's parametric approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a direct anylytical solution for t[r] if you make use of the identiy [image]

```
tsol = t /. First@DSolve[{1/t'[r] == r^2/3 (1 - r), t[2] == 0}, t, r]

(*   Function[{r}, (1/(2 r))
3 (-2 + r + 2 I \[Pi] r - 2 r Log[2] - 2 r Log[1 - r] + 2 r Log[r])]   *)

tsol[r] // FullSimplify[#, 1 < r < 2] &

(*   3/2 - 3/r - 3 Log[-1 + r] + Log[r^3/8]   *)

ParametricPlot[{tsol[r], r}, {r, 1, 2}, AspectRatio -> .8, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {.95, 2.05}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, .95}
]
```

[image]